# Code for Changing Background Image On Scroll Several Times to Create Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, background-image

I was looking at [this site](http://www.dementialab.org/discovery-lab/) and noticed how the background image seems to move and animate as the user scrolls. Upon inspection of the source code, it showed that this was achieved by changing the background image as the user scrolls. Essentially, it jumps through many frames of images giving the illusion of an animation.

What would be the quickest and easiest way to achieve this? I am using the ScrollMagic library if that would make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest, easiest way is to listen for scroll events on the element, then change the background url via CSS to the file you want to show. You'll probably need to convert the pure scroll value to a percentage (to account for varying screen sizes), and you'll need an array of images that map to those percentages.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Would you be able to type up a quick sample code with the key concepts that I can build on?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that does it with colors. Just swap the colors with images. The concept is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/PV5hn/1/

Comment: For some reason, it's not working with images. I believe I have the right url and the right attached files because it works with colors, and when I use the same url as I used in the first element of the image array for as a background image, it works, but not in the array. Is there a different file path? I included my script within the html document.

Comment: make sure you set the background css as `background:"url("+images[3]+")"`

Comment: that seems to just select the 3rd image in the array as the background?

Comment: I did        background:"url("+images[Math.floor(percentScrolled * images.length)]+")"      and that worked, but the problem is the image flashes when scrolling. How can I fix that?

Comment: 2 options: 1. preload the images, or 2. composite them all into one image and instead of replacing the image, simply change the background position.

Comment: how would I change the background image position as a function of the percent of the page scrolled, like you did when changing the background image array number.

Comment: Another wierd question and then I promise I'm done. Since I have a lot of background images to cycle through (like 200), rather than copy all their urls into the array, is there a more efficient code. Their names are image001, image002, ... image200.

Comment: Both of these questions are related since you can determine mathematically which image (or image position) you want to display, you should write functions that return the correct value. Here's a different fiddle that has the code to change between `image001 ...` http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/PV5hn/2/

Comment: I was actually just looking at the original code using it with images and the issues is that the image moves as the user scrolls. I need the image not to move but simply switch to a different background image

Comment: switch the element that gets the CSS background to the container element

Comment: it doesn't work. I just replaced $content to $container